# Parameters of focus graph space (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, bar-chart

I try to understand how to make a bar chart with focus option on basis of the example (the link is below) using d3.js.

The problem is: when it`s need to zoom some bars, for instance, 38, there is the interval between them, but when I select some more bars this interval disappears and bars stick together, there is no space between them.

So, how can I parametrize focus graph scope `focusGraph.attr("?", )` [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JGytk/) , specify its max size. For example, if in the focus scope the interval between bars is less than 4-5px, further expansion of this scope will be impossible - its max size will be achieved.

Comment: It would be easier if you posted the code you already tried.

Comment: Not an answer but **just a comment on usage**, FWIW: what I normally get out of this chart has more to do with narrowing down the x scale so as to deal with less values at a time than to see the shape of those values magnified (e.g. width of the bars). So, I just simply leave the actual shape dimensions alone (in your case, leave the width at 5) and the spacing problem does not manifest itself.